# Broken image in ng-repeat that will not go away

Tags: angularjs

I tried ng-hide and ng-if and no matter what I do, the console log shows a broken image with empty values like this:

```
%7B%7B%20bookings.country%20%7D%7D.png:1 
GET http://localhost:8080/img/flagNations/%7B%7B%20bookings.country%20%7D%7D.png 
404 (Not Found)
```

And here is the code that causes this:

```
<table class="start-table" ng-if="vm.doubleBookings.length > 0">
<tbody>
    <tr ng-repeat="bookings in vm.doubleBookings" class="start-text">
        <td class="start-left">
            <img src="./img/flagNations/{{ bookings.country }}.png" class="start-flag">
            <b class="start-country">{{ bookings.country | uppercase }}</b> 
            {{ bookings.name }}
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Looks like it still tries to render the image even thou there is no data, and it totally ignores the `ng-if="vm.doubleBookings.length > 0"`

Just to confirm, here is from my controller

```
    }).then(function successCallback(result) {
        console.log('from getDoubleBooking: ' + JSON.stringify(result.data.res, null, 4))
        var res = result.data.res;
        console.log("LENGTH RES: " + res.doubleBooking.length)
        vm.doubleBookings = res.doubleBooking; 
        console.log("LENGTH VM: " + vm.doubleBookings.length)
```

Which gives the result

```
from getDoubleBooking: {
    "doubleBooking": [],
    "sameDayBooking": []
}
LENGTH RES: 0
LENGTH VM: 0
```

I seriously cannot figure this one out - it makes no sense why it should render the image?!?

I even tried this:

`<img ng-if="vm.doubleBookings.length > 0" src="./img/flagNations/{{ bookings.country }}.png" class="start-flag">`

same result.

Here is a bigger part of the controller:

```
// 
// Find Double Bookings and Same Day Bookings
// 
var findDoubleBooking = () => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    $http({
        method: 'POST',
        url: globalSetting.serverURL + 'manager/getDoubleBooking',
        headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
        data: {"checkout" : 5299014799}
    }).then(function successCallback(result) {
        console.log('from getDoubleBooking: ' + JSON.stringify(result.data.res, null, 4))
        var res = result.data.res;
        console.log("LENGTH RES: " + res.doubleBooking.length)
        vm.doubleBookings = res.doubleBooking; 
        console.log("LENGTH VM: " + vm.doubleBookings.length)
        vm.sameDayBookings = res.sameDayBooking; 
        console.log("LENGTH VM: " + vm.sameDayBookings.length)

        resolve();
    }, function errorCallback(err) {
        reject(new Error('getDoubleBooking ERROR : ' + err));
    });
})};
```

And here is the whole HTML segment

```
<!--Double Bookings Table-->
<table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" class="start-table start-double-table" ng-if="vm.doubleBookings.length > 0">
<tbody>
    <tr class="start-header start-bold start-double-bg">
        <td colspan="5" class="start-padding overflow">
            DOUBLE BOOKINGS - FIX THEM NOW!
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="start-header start-head start-double-bg">
        <td class="start-left nowrap" style="min-width:76px;">Property</td>
        <td class="start-center overflow" style="width:13%">Checkin</td>
        <td class="start-center overflow" style="width:13%">Checkout</td>
        <td class="start-left overflow" style="width:44%">Tenant</td>
        <td class="start-right overflow" style="width:10%">Paid</td>
    </tr>

    <tr ng-repeat="bookings in vm.doubleBookings" class="start-text">
        <td class="start-left start-border nowrap" ng-class="{'start-double': !$last && bookings.property !== vm.doubleBookings[$index + 1].property}">
            <span class="chan-{{ bookings.source }}">{{ bookings.source }}</span>&nbsp;{{ bookings.property }}
        </td>
        <td class="start-center start-border overflow" ng-class="{'start-double': !$last && bookings.property !== vm.doubleBookings[$index + 1].property}">{{bookings.checkin*1000 | date : 'dd MMM' }}</td>
        <td class="start-center start-border overflow" ng-class="{'start-double': !$last && bookings.property !== vm.doubleBookings[$index + 1].property}">{{bookings.checkout*1000 | date : 'dd MMM' }}</td>
        <td class="start-left start-border overflow" ng-class="{'start-double': !$last && bookings.property !== vm.doubleBookings[$index + 1].property}">
            <img ng-if="vm.doubleBookings.length > 0" src="./img/flagNations/{{ bookings.country }}.png" class="start-flag">
            <b class="start-country">{{ bookings.country | uppercase }}</b> 
            {{ bookings.name }}
        </td>
        <td class="start-right start-border overflow" ng-class="{'start-double': !$last && bookings.property !== vm.doubleBookings[$index + 1].property}">{{ bookings.paidAlready }}</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
<div class="spacer" ng-if="vm.doubleBookings.length > 0"></div>
```

Comment: Might need you to reveal more of the controller code to try replicate your issue.

Comment: Samuel Toh, please have a look now

Comment: Strange thing is even with data I still get the same broken image error and I checked that there are valid country in all data.

Comment: what is `$scope.vm.doubleBookings` initialized as?

Comment: `export default function startController($scope, $http, $interval) {
    var vm = this;
    vm.init = function() {`

Comment: Since angular thinks `vm.doubleBookings.length` has got stuff. Any chance you can print the length of it like doing `{{ xx.length }}` even better if u can JSON.stringify it.

Comment: I tried to put in this one `<b class="start-country">{{ vm.doubleBookings.length }}</b>` and it printed ´0´

Comment: I also tried this `<b class="start-country">>> {{ JSON.stringify(vm.doubleBookings) }} << </b>`  and it returned `>> <<`

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
<img src="./img/flagNations/{{ bookings.country }}.png">
```

I changed `src=` to `ng-src=`

```
<img ng-src="./img/flagNations/{{ bookings.country }}.png">
```

And the problem is gone!!